# Cannot read property of undefined MVC model web service with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Decided to learn some web service development and rain into a problem. I cant seem to find a way how to use ExpressJS Router() to pass POST data to the controller files that i have. When i read contents of the request that was rerouted from product.route.js to the product.controllerjs i get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

File structure as follows:

```
nodeTutorial/
    app.js
    controllers/
       product.controller.js
    models/
       product.model.js
    routes/
       product.route.js
```

Node.js Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
         "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
         "express": "^4.16.4",
         "mongoose": "^5.4.1"
}
```

After hours of debugging i was able to get the request data without using any of the Express routing and just simply retrieve the data within the app.js by doing

```
app.post('/hello', function(req, res){
    console.log("name: " + req.body.name + "; price: " + req.body.price);
    res.json({requestBody: req.body})
});
```

This is good, but i would like to stay a little more organized and not put everything into a single file.

**app.js code**

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const product = require('./routes/product.route'); // Imports routes for the products
const app = express();


// Set up mongoose connection
//........

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/products', product);

//Method that worked for me here (explained above)

let port = 1234;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up and running on port number ' + port);
});
```

**product.route.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const product_controller = 
require('../controllers/product.controller');

router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);

module.exports = router;
```

**product.controller.js**

```
const Product = require('../models/product.model');

//Below is where i need to retrieve data from req
//As of now it prints 'req: undefined'
//And TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
exports.product_create = function (req, res) {
    console.log("req: "+ req.params.name);//doesnt work
    //Also tried all of the below and all return undefied or an Empty Object
    console.log("req.params.name: "+req.params.name);
    console.log("req.params: "+ req.params);
    console.log("req: "+ req.param("name"));
    console.log("req.query.name: "+ req.query.name);
    console.log("req.query: "+ req.query);
    console.log("req.body.name: "+ req.body.name);
    console.log("req.body: "+ req.body);
    console.log("TEST");
    let product = new Product(
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price
         }
};
```

**product.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

When following post request is sent with name and price as body parameters i need to print them out and assign to Product Object

```
POST /products/create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
name=apple%2Cprice=15
```

Sorry in advance if this is a simple solution, i am new to this whole web service thing.

Comment: You are sending Get request or Post request?

Comment: in your console.log statement, you are mentioning as a req.params, instead of req.body. req.params will work on GET.

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify properly. I need POST request to work. I have updated all the console.log that i have tried.

Comment: This is called routing. Since you're using express, check the documentation for [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). It's easy to follow and understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to handle product related routes in product.controller.

In your app.js, `app.use('/products',product.controller)`

In product.controller,

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

router.get('/create',(req,res)=>{//your code})
```

Comment: Wow all i had to do is change `app.use('/products', product);` inside app.js to `app.use('/products',product.controller)` and kept everything else the same. Now i can access POST request body parameters by doing `req.body.name`. Can you explain why that works?

Comment: @OskarDauksts  because `app.use` is express middleware. Basically what nit says is, anythring related to `'/products'`, send it to product.controller, along with the request data

Comment: What confuses me is that how does it know to still go through the `product.route.js`? Because when i remove `router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);` in the `product.route.js` it does't know to send it to `product.controller.js`.

Comment: Because it is not going through `product.route.js`. It goes straight to product.controller

Comment: @OskarDauksts this is where it happens: `router.get('/create',(req,res)=>{//your code})` this will resolve to '/products/create' because in app.js `/products` is sent to `product.controller`, so in `product.controller`, `'/create'` means '/products/create'. And `(req,res)=>{ }` is an anonymous function that will be invoked everytime you make a get request to that route